# perform openssl encryption in c#

Tags: c#, .net, openssl

I'm trying to replicate the following openssl command in .Net

```
 openssl dgst -sha1 -sign PrivateKey.pem -out Record1.sha1 Record1.txt

 openssl enc -base64 -in Record1.sha1 -out Record1.b64 -A
```

which I would get a result like this.
     oso2FoOw4V94ICwKTrv6xwzUrOtxBWCwUOyLVAgKwfOCNKZHMETGIXZZC4spRSyby1uDXBgg

```
 plogrl8gHnvevA00OEoAvGJo9Fa3DOAOMhZNDa9/rNvu71pp+OzHmN2ra5lWpiHcgmUYxm5gamL

 Bk49rkgvl7h1myKCYBKggu60=
```

I would prefer to find a solution where I don't need a third party library.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your question looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819507/creating-digital-signature-in-with-rsa-using-public-and-private-key-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: This article explains how to import a private key in PEM format: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210576/RSA-private-key-import-from-PEM-format-in-Csharp